# What is the correct VCS Username settings with Github so that "My Changes" works correctly?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a TeamCity continuous build process setup for a personal [GitHub project](https://github.com/benpowell/HelloTxt.NET) which works well. However, in TeamCity I want to see a list of commits under "My Changes" (`http://teamcity/changes.html`).

Under "VCS Username Settings" (`http://teamcity/vcsSettings.html`) I have set the username as "benpowell" to match my Github account and as you can see [all commits](https://github.com/benpowell/HelloTxt.NET/commits/master) are logged under that name. However, none of the commits are logged under "My Changes".

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the correct VCS username open up TeamCity and view your build. Under **Recent History** you'll see a column that is called **Changes**, which links to the commit/push that triggered the build (if you have continuous integration setup).

The username is shown there as seen below in the [image: screenshot]:

Notably, the username does appear to be linked to my email address. It is the username part of my Gmail address. I'm assuming Github extracted that, because I wouldn't have chosen that username personally.

Answer (score 10):

One note that might help is that TeamCity has a "Username style" setting under the VCS root itself. For a new installation of TeamCity 9.0.1, it defaulted to just "Userid". I had to go in and change it to "Author Email". **Note** - this setting is hidden under "advanced options".

Per the screen, it will only affect newly collected changes from source.

Once this is done, you should be able to use email addresses under VCS Username successfully.

See the screenshot for more details on this setting:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found [this post](http://blog.petegoo.com/2015/03/14/teamcity-github/) helpful. There are three things that determine the user bindings between your commits to git and build information in TeamCity:

1. **Setting the correct git identity in your local clone** (i.e. `git config user.name`, and also `user.email`). This is how git stamps your commits.
2. **Establishing the mapping between your git identity and your TeamCity identity.** This is done by setting the *UserName Style* in the advanced settings of your VCS roots.
3. **Setting the default username in the *Version Control Username Settings* in your TeamCity user profile.** This is the value that will be used as the lookup key by the mapping you specified in #2.

So, for example, assume a user has a local clone git identity of *user.name* `JCoder` and *user.email* `joe.coder@foo.com` (#1 above), and *UserName Style* of `UserId` (#2) above, and a TeamCity account with the *Name* `Joseph Coder` and *Version Control Username Setting* of `joe.coder` (#3) above.

TeamCity will correctly attribute this user's changes (in build history, for example) to the TeamCity user `Joseph Coder`. This is because the *UserName Style* of `UserId` maps between git and TeamCity users by using the email prefix of *user.email*, `joe.coder` in this case. Note that there are several *Username Styles* (mapping styles). I stick with `UserId` because it uses the email address which is typically the most stable identifier.

Answer (score 1):

With GitHub you need to add the email address used in the commits to your GitHub account for it to see them as your commits.

Comment: This was helpful in that it gave me an idea of where to look, but it was not correct.

Comment: This worked for me.  In TC, per Junto's answer, it showed "fname lname <myemail@domain.com>"  When I went into TC's "Version Control Username Settings" and changed my "Default for all of the Git roots" to "myemail@domain.com" I was able to see all of "My Changes"  Note: this was on TC Enterprise 8.0.4 (build 27616).