# TeamCity not sending email notifications

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0, email-notifications

I am trying to set up an email notification in TeamCity on my project fail. I have set up some user with their information, but when my project fails. i dont get any email.

I have given all the information in 'Email Notofication' tab and did 'Test Connection' giving my email address and it says connection successful. Just wanted to confirm, should i be expecting/getting an email when testing connection with my email address or system just pings/checks if connection is ok?

In my 'Settings and Tools' (under administrator), i have one watched project under 'Email Notifier' which watches for build fail for my project.

Did anyone encountered this problem before, any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, I noticed that I also had a "connection successful" dialog after I pressed the 'test connection' button in teamcity 8 but there was no test message sent.

The trouble was I just had "TeamCity" in the circled area below and not "TeamCity@bolinger.ca". As soon as I added the @bolinger.ca the messages started to go through.

I guess there needs to be some better error handling in TC for this case.

I'm using IIS 6.0 smtp server, but I'm sure sendmail or any other mail server for that matter would not appreciate this error.

[image]

Comment: This sorted my issue out too! 10.0.5

Answer (score 4):

You have to ensure that the VCS username setting in your TeamCity account [matches how it is configured in the VCS root.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993717/495796)

Answer (score 2):

When testing connection with your email address, you should receive a test email.

If you didn't receive any test email but it said connection successful, my experience is that sometimes the email ends up in your Junk mail folder. Please check if that is the case.

And if that is not the case, I suggest testing the SMTP server your teamcity server uses, following this guide:

[How to test a SMTP server by using telnet](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml)

Comment: i tried looking in my server logs and cant find anything when i test my connection, is it that email isnt getting generated at all?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, to successfully setting up SMTP server, you will have to do the following:

After logging-into TeamCity, you will see a dropdown next to your username on top-right.

1. Select "My settings & tools".
2. Under "Watched Builds and Notifications", edit the "Email notifier" settings to indicate when you should be notified via email.

So, our case, we have configured the admin's email id to be project-developers' group email id, so that every one gets an email about build status.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your users have email addresses (I made this mistake!)